# Subtract blocks of rows that match the criteria using r

Tags: r

I would like to subtract blocks of rows from a dataframe, then do more calculations.
For example, I want to subtract blocks of rows in each *grp* variable matching the following criteria:

- 1, the start of the block is satisfying the following conditions:

  - the *val* variable is negative with the *time* variable equals 1;
  - or *val* variable is negative following a positive  *val* variable
- 2, the end of the block is satisfying the following conditions:

  - the *val* variable is positive following a negative *val* variable

```
df <- tribble(
  ~grp, ~time, ~val,
  "A",  1,     1,
  "A",  2,    -0.3,
  "A",  3,    -0.4,
  "A",  5,     0.5,
  "A",  7,    -0.1,
  "A",  9,     0.9,
  "B",  1,    -0.1,
  "B",  2,    -0.4,
  "B",  3,     0.3,
  "B",  5,     0.1,
  "B",  7,     0.4,
  "B",  9,     -0.1
)
```

According to the above criteria, we want to get the following data frame:

```
result <- tribble(
  ~grp, ~time, ~val,
  "A",  2,    -0.3,
  "A",  3,    -0.4,
  "A",  5,     0.5,
  "A",  7,    -0.1,
  "A",  9,     0.9,
  "B",  1,    -0.1,
  "B",  2,    -0.4,
  "B",  3,     0.3
)
```

Using the *result* data frame, we could calculate the state transition time from negative to positive.

```
final <- tribble(
  ~grp, ~tran_time, 
  "A",  (5-2) + (9-7),   
  "B",  3-1
)
```

[Figure of blocks of rows to be substracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToaE1.png)

I could write loop to achieve these aims, but could use vectorised approach to achieve above aims?

Comment: `filter` and `lag`/`lead` of {dplyr} should do the trick

Comment: The window of lag or lead is difficult to determine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your logic, we can use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df |> 
    slice(which.max((val < 0 & time == 1) | (val < 0 & lag(val) > 0)):max(which(lag(val) < 0 & val > 0)))

  grp    time   val
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         2  -0.3
2 A         3  -0.4
3 A         5   0.5
4 A         7  -0.1
5 A         9   0.9
6 B         1  -0.1
7 B         2  -0.4
8 B         3   0.3
```

You can use `count` and `add_count` instead of `group_by` to summarise the trans time

```
df2 <- df1 |> 
    add_count(a = ifelse(val < 0, cumsum(val > 0) + 1, cumsum(val > 0)), wt = max(time) - min(time)) |> 
    count(grp, wt = sum(unique(n)), name = "trans_time")

  grp   trans_time
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 A              5
2 B              2
```

Comment: Thank you, James. Your solution is great.  It's a new way to use slice() function that I have learned.